# Virtual Environment "no module named" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a virtual environment set up running Python 3.5.  I ran my source command and ran pip to install beatbox:

```
(venv) Daniels-Air:bin danieldow$ pip list
beatbox (32.1)
pip (8.1.2)
requests (2.11.0)
setuptools (25.1.6)
six (1.10.0)
slack (0.0.2)
slackclient (1.0.1)
websocket-client (0.37.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

However, when I try to import I get:

```
    (venv) Daniels-Air:bin danieldow$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import beatbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/danieldow/venv-python3/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/beatbox/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _beatbox import _tPartnerNS, _tSObjectNS, _tSoapNS, SoapFaultError, SessionTimeoutError
ImportError: No module named '_beatbox'
```

In the directory for beatbox in site packages the -beatbox module is there:

```
(venv) Daniels-Air:site-packages danieldow$ pwd
/Users/danieldow/venv-python3/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages
(venv) Daniels-Air:site-packages danieldow$ cd beatbox
(venv) Daniels-Air:beatbox danieldow$ ls
__init__.py     _beatbox.py     python_client.py
__pycache__     marshall.py     xmltramp.py
```

Can someone tell mw what I'm doing wrong or anything I can try?

Thanks!

Dan

*PS In Pycharm, under interpreter, it does show the package as being installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that beatbox was written for Python 2.x.  'pip instal beatbox3' and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You have soluted this problem. But I will tell you some thing more.

In Python, please run these code:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

this will print the environment variable. If you find these environment variable is your system Python's instead of your venv Python, then the reason must one of these two reasons:

1. you have writen alias in `.zshrc`, and point `python` to system's python path. If so, just delete the alias.
2. the softlink of your python in venv is broken. it can not find the right place of python binary. If so, rebuild the softlink or recreate a venv and use the parameter: --copy  `virutalenv venv --copy`